# npm and node update message on VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

"Ensure `node` and `npm` are installed to enable automatically reporting issues in source files pertaining to accessibility, compatibility, security, and more."

I have installed npm and Node js (both latest version) and checked multiple times. Still I am getting this message frequently on VS Code. I could not find any plausible reason on my local environment or searching the web.

My environment details:
Windows 11;
npm 8.11.0;
node 16.15.1.

Is there anything that can affect my projects? I am working on a extension development (beginner level).

What's triggering this message and how do I resolve this issue?
Update: It is affecting my projects.

Comment: What happens if you type `node -v` in your terminal?

Comment: @Wyck it shows v16.15.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, all the inconsistent behaviors by the machine I am on have been resolved.

After trying multiple things, I reset Windows by 'remove everything'. It worked like a wizard. I, then, installed Node, VS Code and Yeoman. They all worked without any problem on the very first attempt.

My experience is Windows 11 likely to have some built-in issues since it's very new.

Comment: This annoying message appears in Windows 10 as well.

Comment: @RubemPechansky did you Reset Windows? If not, how did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I did at least one Windows reset. The problem is still there, it's not solved yet.

Comment: @RubemPechansky Did you choose 'Remove Everything' while the reset?

Comment: If by "everything" you mean uninstalling npm and node, no. I just reset Windows, nothing else.

Comment: while resetting Windows, there is an option 'Remove Everything'. I selected that and it worked for me.

In my case, something was twisted at OS level. So, it resolved that.

Comment: You can take a look at this one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugdHVJTfMII